# Number of Different Subsequences GCDs

Tags: python-3.x, greatest-common-divisor

Number of Different Subsequences GCDs

You are given an array nums that consists of positive integers.

The GCD of a sequence of numbers is defined as the greatest integer that divides all the numbers in the sequence evenly.

For example, the GCD of the sequence [4,6,16] is 2.
A subsequence of an array is a sequence that can be formed by removing some elements (possibly none) of the array.

For example, [2,5,10] is a subsequence of [1,2,1,2,4,1,5,10].
Return the number of different GCDs among all non-empty subsequences of nums.

Example 1:

Input: nums = [6,10,3]
Output: 5
Explanation: The figure shows all the non-empty subsequences and their GCDs.
The different GCDs are 6, 10, 3, 2, and 1.

```
from itertools import permutations
import math

class Solution:
    def countDifferentSubsequenceGCDs(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        s = set()
        g =0
        for i  in range(1,len(nums)+1):
            comb = combinations(nums,i)
            for i in comb:
                if len(i)==1:
                    u = i[0]
                    s.add(u)
                else:
                    g = math.gcd(i[0],i[1])
                    s.add(g)
                    if len(i)>2:
                        for j in range(2,len(i)):
                            g = math.gcd(g,i[j])
                            s.add(g)
                            g = 0
        y = len(s)
        return y
```

I am getting TLE for this input. Can someone pls help?

[5852,6671,170275,141929,2414,99931,179958,56781,110656,190278,7613,138315,58116,114790,129975,144929,61102,90624,60521,177432,57353,199478,120483,75965,5634,109100,145872,168374,26215,48735,164982,189698,77697,31691,194812,87215,189133,186435,131282,110653,133096,175717,49768,79527,74491,154031,130905,132458,103116,154404,9051,125889,63633,194965,105982,108610,174259,45353,96240,143865,184298,176813,193519,98227,22667,115072,174001,133281,28294,42913,136561,103090,97131,128371,192091,7753,123030,11400,80880,184388,161169,155500,151566,103180,169649,44657,44196,131659,59491,3225,52303,141458,143744,60864,106026,134683,90132,151466,92609,120359,70590,172810,143654,159632,191208,1497,100582,194119,134349,33882,135969,147157,53867,111698,14713,126118,95614,149422,145333,52387,132310,108371,127121,93531,108639,90723,416,141159,141587,163445,160551,86806,120101,157249,7334,60190,166559,46455,144378,153213,47392,24013,144449,66924,8509,176453,18469,21820,4376,118751,3817,197695,198073,73715,65421,70423,28702,163789,48395,90289,76097,18224,43902,41845,66904,138250,44079,172139,71543,169923,186540,77200,119198,184190,84411,130153,124197,29935,6196,81791,101334,90006,110342,49294,67744,28512,66443,191406,133724,54812,158768,113156,5458,59081,4684,104154,38395,9261,188439,42003,116830,184709,132726,177780,111848,142791,57829,165354,182204,135424,118187,58510,137337,170003,8048,103521,176922,150955,84213,172969,165400,111752,15411,193319,78278,32948,55610,12437,80318,18541,20040,81360,78088,194994,41474,109098,148096,66155,34182,2224,146989,9940,154819,57041,149496,120810,44963,184556,163306,133399,9811,99083,52536,90946,25959,53940,150309,176726,113496,155035,50888,129067,27375,174577,102253,77614,132149,131020,4509,85288,160466,105468,73755,4743,41148,52653,85916,147677,35427,88892,112523,55845,69871,176805,25273,99414,143558,90139,180122,140072,127009,139598,61510,17124,190177,10591,22199,34870,44485,43661,141089,55829,70258,198998,87094,157342,132616,66924,96498,88828,89204,29862,76341,61654,158331,187462,128135,35481,152033,144487,27336,84077,10260,106588,19188,99676,38622,32773,89365,30066,161268,153986,99101,20094,149627,144252,58646,148365,21429,69921,95655,77478,147967,140063,29968,120002,72662,28241,11994,77526,3246,160872,175745,3814,24035,108406,30174,10492,49263,62819,153825,110367,42473,30293,118203,43879,178492,63287,41667,195037,26958,114060,99164,142325,77077,144235,66430,186545,125046,82434,26249,54425,170932,83209,10387,7147,2755,77477,190444,156388,83952,117925,102569,82125,104479,16506,16828,83192,157666,119501,29193,65553,56412,161955,142322,180405,122925,173496,93278,67918,48031,141978,54484,80563,52224,64588,94494,21331,73607,23440,197470,117415,23722,170921,150565,168681,88837,59619,102362,80422,10762,85785,48972,83031,151784,79380,64448,87644,26463,142666,160273,151778,156229,24129,64251,57713,5341,63901,105323,18961,70272,144496,18591,191148,19695,5640,166562,2600,76238,196800,94160,129306,122903,40418,26460,131447,86008,20214,133503,174391,45415,47073,39208,37104,83830,80118,28018,185946,134836,157783,76937,33109,54196,37141,142998,189433,8326,82856,163455,176213,144953,195608,180774,53854,46703,78362,113414,140901,41392,12730,187387,175055,64828,66215,16886,178803,117099,112767,143988,65594,141919,115186,141050,118833,2849]

Comment: I didn't downvote, but what is "TLE" supposed to mean?

Comment: TLE means "time limit exceeded" - the program site he ran this on said his program took too long to finish the example.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to add "an answer" here because most "not horribly slow" programs I've seen for this are way too elaborate.

Call the input `xs`. The fastest way I know of asks, for each integer `j` in `1` through `max(xs)`, can `j` be the gcd of some non-empty subset of `xs`?  Of course if `max(xs)` can be huge, that can be slow. But in the context you apparently took this from (LeetCode), it cannot be huge.

So, given `j`, how do we know whether some subset's gcd is `j`? Actually easy! We look at all and only the multiples of `j` in `xs`. The gcd of all of those is *at least* `j`. If, at any point along the way, their gcd so far *is* `j`, we found a subset whose gcd is `j`. Else the running gcd exceeds `j` after processing all of `j`'s multiples, so no subset's gcd is `j`.

```py
def numgcds(xs):
    from math import gcd

    limit = max(xs) + 1
    result = 0
    xsset = set(xs)

    for j in range(1, limit):
        g = 0
        for x in range(j, limit, j):
            if x in xsset:
                g = gcd(x, g)
                if g == j:
                    result += 1
                    break
    return result
```

Where `L` is `max(xs)`, worst-case runtime is `O(L * log(L))`. Across outer loop iterations, the inner loop goes around (at worst) `L` times at first, then `L/2` times, then `L/3`, and so on. That sums to `L*(1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/L)`. The second factor (the sum of reciprocals) is the `L`'th "[harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)", and is approximately the natural logarithm of `L`.

### More Gonzo

I don't really like having the runtime depend on the largest integer in the input. For example, `numgcds([20000000])` takes 20 million iterations of the outer loop to determine that there's only one gcd, and can take appreciable time (about 30 seconds on my box just now).

Instead, with more code, we can build some dicts that eliminate all searching. For each divisor `d` of an integer in `xs`, `d2xs[d]` is the list of multiples of `d` in `xs`. The keys of `d2xs` are the only possible gcds we need to check, and a key's associated values are exactly (no searching needed) the multiples of the key in `xs`.

The collection of all possible divisors of all integers in `xs` can be found by factoring each integer in `xs`, and generating all possible combinations of its factors' prime powers.

This is harder to code, but can run very much faster. `numgcds([20000000])` is essentially instant.  And it runs about 10 times faster for the largish example you gave.

```py
def gendivisors(x):
    from collections import Counter
    from itertools import product
    from math import prod

    c = Counter(factor(x))
    pows = []
    for p, k in c.items():
        pows.append([p**i for i in range(k+1)])
    for t in product(*pows):
        yield prod(t)

def numgcds(xs):
    from math import gcd
    from collections import defaultdict

    d2xs = defaultdict(list)
    for x in xs:
        for d in gendivisors(x):
            d2xs[d].append(x)
    result = 0
    for j, mults in d2xs.items():
        g = 0
        for x in mults:
            g = gcd(x, g)
            if g == j:
                result += 1
                break
    return result
```

I'm not including code for `factor(n)` - pick your favorite. The code requires it return an iterable (list, generator iterator, tuple, doesn't matter) of all `n`'s prime factors. Order doesn't matter. As special cases, `list(factor(i))` should return `[i]` for `i` equal to 0 or 1.

For ordinary cases, `list(factor(p)) == [p]` for a prime `p`, and, e.g., `sorted(factor(20)) == [2, 2, 5]`.

Worst-case timing is much harder to nail, but the key bit is that a reasonable implementation of `factor(n)` will have worst-case time `O(sqrt(n))`.